# compare generic struct values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

i want to compare 2 generic values and to achieve this i use something like this:

```
public TEntity Get(TKey key) where TKey: struct
{
    if (!key.GetType().IsPrimitive)
    {
       throw new Exception($"Repository->Get: given type {key.GetType().Name} is not supported");
    }
    return _dbSet.Single(x=> x.Id.ToString().Equals(key.ToString()));
}
```

if I just use

```
x.Id.Equals(key)
```

throws Exception

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Is there another way to do that without using `toString()`

**Edit:**

got answer in comments to use `Find` method but it is just part of answer, what if I want use `Where` method?

**Edit2:**

accepted answer fully solved my problem, just changed `struct` restriction to 
`IEquatable`

Comment: And what is the type of x.Id?

Comment: x.Id same type TKey as key

Comment: You need to implement `IEquatable<T>` and then make that the constraint. You need to see if objects are equal not convert them.

Comment: I changed to restrict struct

Comment: @CodingYoshi This looks like EF though...

Comment: yes, this is EF

Comment: I've retagged your question, making it EF has a large difference as to what is possible.

Comment: I do not think this has anything to do with EF. Your generic code needs to see if 2 things are equal so you need to make sure they implement the right interface. Why would you restrict them to IConvertible if your generic code has nothing to do with conversion.

Comment: this is just simple `struct`s and i need to compare them I don't that I need to implement some kind of interface

Comment: `x.Id == key` Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TKey' and 'TKey'

Comment: @CodingYoshi Yes because OP is dealing with `IQueryable` here so implementing `IEquatable` would just confuse EF.

Comment: @Sonikas The [`DbSet.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx) method already does this for you by the way.

Comment: @DavidG I understand what you mean. However, what I am trying to say is that the generic code has nothing to do with IConvertible. If it is used with EF then the implementation of IEquatable should handle that.

Comment: Why Primitive types only? this will prevent you from using strings or Guid.

Comment: for now I plan to use only int values as keys, but yes maybe it is good idea to extend possibility to use Guids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current version, when you do:

```
_dbSet.Single(x=> x.Id.Equals(key));
```

since type of key can be arbitrary, object.Equals(object) overload is used, so your `key` should be casted to `object`. EF has a problem with that because it sees you use constant (as in `Expression.Constant`) of type `object`, and you cannot use arbitrary types in SQL, so it says right away that it won't be able to convert your `object` constant to sql.

You can fix that by forcing your `TKey` to implement `IEquatable<TKey>`:

```
where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
```

Then when you do

```
_dbSet.Single(x=> x.Id.Equals(key));
```

`IEquatable<TKey>.Equals(TKey)` version of Equals will be used, which requires no cast of your `key` to `object`. EF doesn't really care about that interface specifically. When parsing your query it sees method with name "Equals" and compatible signature, that's all it cares about. Because of that, you can also do something like this instead of requiring `IEquatable<TKey>`:

```
public static class EfHelpers {
    public static bool Equals<TKey>(TKey key, TKey other) {
        // not intended to call directly
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public TEntity Get(TKey key) {
    // method has name "Equals", compatible signature and does not require
    // casting to object, so we are fine
    return _dbSet.Single(x => EfHelpers.Equals(x.Id, key));
}
```

But I won't recommend doing that in this particular case, because all types you care about already implement `IEquatable<T>`. But this technique might be useful in other cases.